# Getting multiple select values?

Tags: php, html, select

I have been having an issue with my PHP code or HTML code, not sure :S
All it's meant to do is extract the chosen options from a select box.

The coding all looks correct to me but it doesn't seem to work?
So if anyone could spot my mistake that would be great!

HTML:

```
<p>Your favourite sport: <select name="sport[]" size="4" multiple="multiple">
                         <option value="soccer">Soccer</option>
                         <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
                         <option value="squash">Squash</option>
                         <option value="golf">Golf</option>
                         <option value="tennis">Tennis</option>
                         <option value="basketball">Basketball</option>
                         <option value="baseball">Baseball</option>
                       </select>
</p>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  foreach ($_POST['sport'] as $val)
  {
  echo $val."\n";
  }
?>
```

Those are the sections of code in my project that i have been working on.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't seem to work"?  Does the code raise an error?  Also, your `foreach` statement should include `{ ... }`.

Comment: oh sorry, when i run the HTML file and hit the sumbit button the error that comes up (i am currently using WAMP to run my site) is "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\Practical 2\task2.php on line 27" and nothing is shown in the space where it should be showing the selected options.

Comment: i have added { ... } to my code now but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Please use print_r() as suggested to find out what $_POST contains. It's the most obvious thing you should have done (apart from not having ignored the error message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and do it this way if you want all the variables from your form:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key.":".$value;
    }
}
```

If you only want the $_POST['sport'] try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['sport'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['sport'] as $val) {
        echo $val."\n";
    }
}
```